# Call Class Function Using A List Of Class Objects Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class that I pass various values (IP address, name, model ect) when I define the class.

At the same time I am putting these classes into a list so I can easily expand the number of devices. I want to be able to call a separate function from the class.

For example

My class looks somewhat like

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, IP, Name, Model, Series):
         #Do stuff
    def getstate():
         #Do more stuff and return a value
```

My list looks somewhat like

```
Devices = {}    #I fill this up with the list of all devices elseware
ClassDevices = []

for key in Devices:
        print 'List is empty, store objects'
        ClassDevices.append(Foo(Devices[key]["IP"], Devices[key], Devices[key]["Model"], Devices[key]["Series"]))
```

The above seems to work but now I want to be able to get the status of each device. I have tried the following

```
print ClassDevices[0].getstate()
```

And I get an error

```
TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

I'm new to Python so I am not even sure if what I am trying to do is possible

Full code (since it probably is easier) can be seen [here](https://github.com/dcplaya/SenseMe/blob/v0.21/Haiku/SmartHome.py)

Comment: I don't think you are showing the entire picture, something is missing here.  Can you paste the whole code?

Comment: full stacktrace please.`[0]` cannot do that.

Comment: `getstate`, since it isn't decorated as a static method, must take at least one argument.

Comment: Full code can be seen at [link](https://github.com/dcplaya/SenseMe/blob/v0.21/Haiku/SmartHome.py)

Code is dirty, I am just learning Python

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on classes in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is pretty simple.  The main issue is that you are not iterating correctly (because you are new to Python).

You have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
for x in SmartHome.SenseMeDevices:
    print(SmartHome.SenseMeDevices[x].getstate())
```

In this case `x` is *already* an element of your list, not an index to an element.

You should instead iterate like this:

```
for x in SmartHome.SenseMeDevices:
    print(x.getstate())
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I cant believe it was so simple but I would have never gotten this on my own.